# How to use for loops in command prompt in csh shell -- looking for decent one liners

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

coming from bash shell, I missed on an easy rolling of loops (for i in (...); do ... done;)

Would you post typical one-liners of loops in cshell?

**ONE LINERS PLEASE, and not multiple-lines**
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I haven't written a `csh` script in years. But Bill Joy did write it himself, I suppose it's worth some nostalgia effort...

```
set t=(*)
foreach i ($t)
  echo $i >> /tmp/z
end
```

or just `foreach i (*)`

This loop structure works well with a built-in concept that csh has of a *word list*. This is sort-of present in bash but not in vanilla posix shells.

```
set q=(how now brown cow)
echo $q[2]
```

The `foreach` loop neatly iterates through this data structure.

Comment: *Update:* Ok, ok, well, I don't know how to do one-liner loops in csh.  The csh grammar handles `;` and newline differently. It's not one-liner friendly.

Answer (score 10):

The `csh` man page states:

> The foreach, switch, and while statements, as well as the if-then-else form of the if statement require that the major keywords appear in a single simple command on an input line as shown below.

and

> Both foreach and end must appear alone on separate lines.

and

> The words else and endif must appear at the beginning of input lines; the if must appear alone on its input line or after an else.

and

> The while and end must appear alone on their input lines.

Comment: See also "flow control" in Csh Programming Considered Harmful: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to get CSH shell to easily loop over and run the same command over.

As pointed out by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1548355/1897481

Made me give up one making a oneliner work.

Finally settled to having the following aliases to run commands with arguments* in a loop:

```
    # while_cmd_w_sleep <SLEEP-TIME> <CMD + ARGS>
    alias while_cmd_w_sleep '(echo '\''while (1)\n\!:2*\necho =================\necho Sleeping for \!:1.\nsleep \!:1\necho =================\nend'\'') | tcsh'

    # for_n_cmd <LOOP_COUNT> <CMD + ARGS>
    alias for_n_cmd         '(echo '\''foreach x (`seq \!:1`)\necho =================\necho Iteration \[$x]\necho =================\n\!:2*\nend'\'') | tcsh'

    # for_n_cmd_w_sleep <LOOP_COUNT> <SLEEP-TIME> <CMD + ARGS>
    alias for_n_cmd_w_sleep '(echo '\''foreach x (`seq \!:1`)\necho =================\necho Iteration \[$x]\necho =================\n\!:3*\necho =================\necho Sleeping for \!:2.\nsleep \!:2\nend'\'') | tcsh'
```

Sample outputs:

```
    $> for_n_cmd 3 echo hi
    =================
    Iteration [1]
    =================
    hi
    =================
    Iteration [2]
    =================
    hi
    =================
    Iteration [3]
    =================
    hi
```

The while loop:

```
    $> while_cmd_w_sleep 2s echo hello there
    hello there
    =================
    Sleeping for 2s.
    =================
    hello there
    =================
    Sleeping for 2s.
    =================
    hello there
    =================
    Sleeping for 2s.
    ^C
```

* Example where multiple commands are run in a loop:

```
    $> for_n_cmd 3 'echo hi\\nsleep 2s\\necho done waiting'
    =================
    Iteration [1]
    =================
    hi
    done waiting
    =================
    Iteration [2]
    =================
    hi
    done waiting
    =================
    Iteration [3]
    =================
    hi
    done waiting
```

In this example, three commands `echo hi`, `sleep 2s` and `echo done waiting` are being run in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that i've fixed it somehow, despite csh options, so you can do something like this:

```
printf "while ( 1 ) \n ps -aux|grep httpd \n echo 'just a new row' \n  sleep 2 \n end" | csh -f
```