# Online if statement in tcsh/csh

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I work on [`tcsh`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tcsh%201), and try to do `if then else endif` statement to check `$?` of the previous command. But I am getting `"if: Empty if."`

```
dude >ps -p $$                                                                                                  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32 pts/82   00:00:00 tcsh
dude >if ( "$?" == "0" ) ; then echo "good" ; endif
if: Empty if.
```

i.e. I want to execute the following:

```
>if ( "$?" == "0" ) then ; echo "good" ; else ; echo "bad" ; endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use bash syntax for tcsh - it should be:

```
if ( "$?" == "0" ) then
   echo "good"
else
   echo "bad"
endif
```

Note that there is no `;` before `then` (like you would have in bash).

Comment: How do I combine an else statement ?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with that syntax how do I rewrite it as one liner

Comment: csh/tcsh are not very "one-liner-friendly" compared to bash. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544325/how-to-use-for-loops-in-command-prompt-in-csh-shell-looking-for-decent-one-li